# Show that a function is continuous on an infinite interval

Tags: limits, continuity

We may show that a function is continuous over an interval $[a,b]$ by applying

$$\lim_{x \to a+} f(x) = f(a) \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x \to b−}f(x) = f(b)$$

But what about on an interval $(-\infty, 3]$ ? How can the definition of 'continuous on an interval' above be applied with an infinite value, seeing as infinity cannot be plugged in to the expression?

Comment: You only need special treatment for a, b in the first case, because they are "one-sided". There is only one "one-sided" point in your second example (namely 3).

Comment: This only shows that the function is continuous at the endpoints. What about the unit step function on the interval $[-1,1]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you don't have to plug in $- \infty$ you have to show the function is continuous at any $a \in [-\infty , 3]$ otherwise you can think alternatively that the function is continuous in $[x,3]$ for any $x \in (-\infty ,3]$

Comment: It should be open interval on 3 at the end because closed intetval 3,3 has no meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, to show that a function is continuous on an interval you need to show that the limits agree at **every** point in the interval:
$$
\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c),\quad c\in (a,b),
$$
in addition to checking the limits at the endpoints as you have written.

For a semi-infinite interval like $(-\infty,3]$, you still need to check the limit at each point in the interior (i.e. all $c\leq 3$ in this case), but there is no limit to check at $-\infty$. You would still check the upper limit at $3$, of course.